# Returning the same JSON list of records, from various sources

Tags: ajax, grails

I'm using Grails 1.3.7. Let's say I have the domain objects *Foo* and *Bar*. Both *Foo* and *Bar* have a list of *Noodle* instances. In *NoodleController*, *FooController* and *BarController*, I've a *fetchNoodles* action which returns a JSON list of records, like this

NoodleController

```
def fetchNoodles = {
  List data = []
  for(noodle in Noodle.list())
    data.add([noodle.id, noodle.name, noodle.stuff]

  render data as JSON
}
```

FooController

```
def fetchNoodles = {
  List data = []

  foo = Foo.get(params.id)
  if (foo) {
    for(noodle in foo.noodles())
      data.add([noodle.id, noodle.name, noodle.stuff]
  }

  render data as JSON
}
```

BarController

```
def fetchNoodles = {
  List data = []

  bar = Bar.get(params.id)
  if (bar) {
    for(noodle in bar.noodles())
      data.add([noodle.id, noodle.name, noodle.stuff]
  }

  render data as JSON
}
```

Questions

- How can I avoid repeating 3 times the same code ?
- How to add filtering to those list fetching actions, still without repeating myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move it to a `NoodleService`. Then, in `BarController`, do it like

```
def noodleService

def fetchNoodles = {
  List data = noodleService.getNoodles(Bar.get(params.id)?.noodles) 
  render data as JSON
}
```

or

```
noodleService.getNoodles(Bar.get(params.id)?.noodles, { it.name =~ /A.+/ }))
```

if we're talking about filtering after retrieving `noodles` collection. If you need to filter `noodles` on database level, you'll need to access them differently, like:

```
noodleService.getNoodles([barId: params.id], params.subMap(
  ['order', 'sort', 'max', 'offset', 'whatever-filter-field-names-here']))
```

and in `NoodleService.getNoodles(Map criteriaFields, Map filterFields)` query `noodles` with a Criteria.